# Deleted by Community not shown on review (audit?) page

Tags: bug, review, deleted-answers, community-user

This question on Meta Stack Overflow: [Why is this answer spam?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357698/4751173) concerns a failed review audit ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/17595044), SO 10k only). It looks a little bit strange, because it doesn't show that the Community ♦ user deleted the post:

[image]

On the other hand, when viewing the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46554067/4751173) directly, it *is* shown:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed with the [New Post Notices roll-out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339700/295232); now both the post itself and the review audit say

> **This post is hidden.** It was [deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) 2 years ago by [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) ♦.

[image]