# Broken image in new post notices blog post

Tags: bug, status-completed, images, blog, post-notices

Broken image in the [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/12/05/new-post-notices-improving-feedback-on-stack-overflow-questions/?cb=1) related to the [New Post Notices are live network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339700/312043) announcement.

> [image: broken image]

The below image source is not available:

```
<img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/e1M4ewSsfWZvFOzItSndgLEeVfPAUdZHmCqkd98Pu_wIggh-A4W-tEFP-lBHz7_953RZ1HZ_4uK-TpJOKpdjfZ6PMT7LnS_pDSOkVYcJJgjQ1h7ApK3q_9pbBm-bKV76GlOGCb-9" alt="">
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pic is back, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Thanks for the quick fix.