# Where's the bump notice?

Tags: bug, status-declined, community-user, bump, post-notices

Does anyone remember this?

> ### **Bumped to the homepage** by [Community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community)♦ 2 hours ago
>
> This question has answers that may be good or bad; the system has marked it active so that they can be reviewed.

With the introduction of the new blue banners it's gone ([example 1](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/505121/191178), [example 2](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4276/37236)), but I found the bump notice helpful since there are several other reasons why Community might have "modified" something (anonymous suggested edit, destroyed answerer).

You can still use the edit history (or timeline) to figure out if it was indeed a bump but that's not very obvious.

Can we get this back in a way that's not super obnoxious?

Comment: I noticed (pun intended) it too: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339885/295232

Comment: Perhaps tag as "[faq-proposed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/faq-proposed/info)"?

Answer (score 3):

We deliberately removed the bump notice.

The data is still there in the message history for those who are in the know and want to look for it. But for almost all users it is not relevant.

(In our opinion) it is not a best practice to give a small technical detail related to post sorting such a visible placement in relation to content. So it is no longer being shown as a post notice.

Comment: "it is not a best practice to give a small technical detail related to post sorting such a visible placement in relation to content." That's a good argument for making it smaller, absolutely. However, it's not an argument to remove it altogether or hiding it in the timeline.

Comment: I agree that a smaller solution would be nice. And it could happen. But it is not even in a place where I feel comfortable putting this in [tag:status-deferred] (which itself includes an implied promise of doing it at some point). What I wrote in the question is all I can definitively say now.

Comment: Well, thank you for the quick response at least :-)

Comment: Sorry Yaakov, this is a post I had to downvote. I think this is a very poor choice, let me explain. If I look at the question list I usually notice whose activity caused it to be in the recent questions. This can be very puzzling in some cases (deleted answers for example), to which you just added another case of confusion.

Comment: I agree with @Luuklag on this one, and disagree with the decision to remove the notice. Knowing what bumped the question is important information.

Comment: I also agree with both of you that it can be puzzling and confusing to see it in the list with no explanation. The challenge is that we can't use a post notice for it anymore, as it is kind of a niche/powerUser-focused notice that is just more confusing for the average user. And we don't have time/resources right now for a "secondary smaller notices" project. If you have any out of the box ideas, happy to hear them.

Comment: @YaakovEllis How about a secondary community user, "Community-bumper" or something in that fashion, that exclusively runs these bumps. Then you can fill the profile of that user with the now gone notice, or even a bit more detailed story.

Comment: I was thinking about things like that, can't make any promises other than that it will be discussed

Comment: The real solution is to make the "revisions" view (or perhaps the timeline view, but I think that one is so busy that it's harder to read) always accessible via a permanent link. Then, power users could click on that to see exactly when the question was last revised, and would see that Community had bumped it. This is the issue with both of the examples identified in the question: there's no obvious way to see why it was bumped. In fact, by all appearances, it was never edited! I see no benefit whatsoever in giving Community an identity crisis.

Comment: How about community user posting a comment that self deletes after one day?

Comment: This is bad form. If you're going to push old junk onto the timeline, tell people about it. I just spent 15 minutes commenting on answers to a question before realizing it's 10 years old.