# Can we have a permanent bye to "on-hold"?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, closed-questions, post-notices, close-dialog

Whenever I click on "Close" button to cast a close vote on an already loaded page of a closed question when it wasn't closed, this dialog appears:

[image]

But since the [redesign of post notices](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339700/468333), "on-hold" isn't a thing anymore. Therefore, I think it's redundant and maybe confusing. In my opinion, the dialog now should have this instead

> This question has been closed since you loaded the page - please refresh and try your action again.

Comment: due to the holiday season applying this change has been put on-hold ...

Comment: I prefer On-Hold

Comment: If nothing else, the hyphen in "on-hold" is not grammatically correct.

Comment: Wasn't the whole purpose of "on hold" to be more welcome towards obnoxious new users, since an outright closure was, well, seen by some as being unwelcoming? This would be counter to the new "be welcoming" culture of the site.

Comment: @Renan Well since now questions only get `[closed]` in the title, so on-hold is confusing, I think. Also, this question is irrelevant for new users since they don't have privileges to vote to close questions :)

Comment: @Kulfy the thing about new users is not about their privileges, is that apparently some were crying when they saw their questions closed so the "on hold" wording made them think that their questions had some hope of reopening. False hope for most of them, but hope somewhat.

Comment: @Renan For that I'd encourage you to post a new question  if "**Where did the "On Hold" label go?**" from the [main post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339700/468333) doesn't help.

Comment: @Kulfy oh I totally missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This has been fixed. `On hold` is no more.