# "On hold" is not yet removed from the privilege pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, privileges, on-hold

As per the [New Post Notices are live network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339700/312043) post, "on hold" label is removed from the post notices (title suffix).

> **Where did the "On Hold" label go?**
>
> "On Hold" had been used to label recently closed questions. The idea was that this language would imply less permanence to the current state than "Closed". However, user research showed that this distinction was generally found to be confusing to users at all levels, and did not seem to have an effect on reopen rates. So we have removed this label. All Closed posts are now labeled as Closed but only the label has changed. Edits within the first five days will still put the question in the reopen queue.

But the same is not updated in the privilege pages.

For example in the [view close votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes)

> **What is a closed question?**
>
> Closed questions do not allow new answers and can be identified by the `[on hold]` or `[closed]` title suffix.

and [cast close and reopen votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) page

> **What happens when a question is closed?**
>
> Once a question has been closed, it will no longer accept new answers and the words `[on hold]` will be appended to the title. After 5 days, if the question remains closed, the word `[closed]` will instead be appended to the title.

So, can the "on hold" related content be removed in privilege pages too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wiki pages have been updated. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the fix. But in the [view close votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes) page, one [typo issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQqQ3.png). Can you please correct that.

Comment: oops. Had an extra `. Fixed

Comment: Suggested edit: "identified by the `[closed]` **or `[duplicate]`** title suffix".