# Question flagged as duplicate, but links to duplicated questions not shown

Tags: bug

The question *in question*: [SQL Server and connection loss in the middle of a transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978372/sql-server-and-connection-loss-in-the-middle-of-a-transaction)

Maybe a bug?

Comment: That's not a bug, that's normal for older question. The dupe link as edited into the question. Someone just edited that out, I rolled that edit back.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [New Post Notices are live network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339700/new-post-notices-are-live-network-wide), especially [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339706/398063) there.

Comment: and [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339700/new-post-notices-are-live-network-wide/339706#comment1134600_339706) from Yaakov.

Comment: Hopefully this duplicate question remains accessible in the future :)