# Migration message for per-site metas make no sense

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration, migration-notice

We don't migrate posts cause they can be answered by professional and enthusiast programmers. We migrate them because they are to do with SO careers, Teams or other products primarily on SO.

> [image: Screenshot of migration message. Says "This question was migrated to Meta Stack Overflow because it can be answered by professional and enthusiast programmers. Migrated 34 seconds ago by Journeyman Geek]

The current wording is somewhat misleading.

Could we have the wording for migration to this site reviewed and corrected?

Comment: While I agree, this is bit complicated. Currently it's taking it from the same source as the [Tour page](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) - after all, Stack Overflow is indeed meant "for professional and enthusiast programmers". Maybe on per-site meta, this can simply be omitted, leaving only "This question was migrated to [site name]", without the "because" part.

Comment: I think I have seen this behavior before and written a bug report about it. I also think that it was deleted (possibly by me). I think this was due to being an exact duplicate. This would apply here too. Can you please take a look @JourneymanGeek

Comment: I saw a similar thing on English Language & Usage migrating to English Language Learning, and assumed that it was something specific to that relationship. But I guess this is now network-wide.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/340409/295232

Comment: @MEE-codidact.org can't find that in your deleted posts , and as such, the master

Comment: The old notices would prepend "our discussion site for our site for" before the text on the Tour page. It seems the new notices are not doing that.

Comment: It seems that this got missed in testing because ordinarily users never see this text. Moderators, as well as users using the `?noredirect=1` parameter within 30 days, do indeed see it. In my opinion, all things should be refined, even if they're bits that most never see.

Comment: [I pinged Yaakov](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394552/4642212/#comment765224_394578). This is a regression, but it’s not the only one: the link to “ask a new one” currently points to `/ask` again, as opposed to `/help/how-to-ask`.

Comment: I'm reviewing this bug right now.  Looking at the code, we show a special messaging if a question has been moved to its site's meta or MSE.  We don't show the message if it's been migrated from MSE to another meta.  That's the problem I think we're experiencing here and problem that's probably isolated to MSE moderators.  We could drop the `destination.IsChildMetaOf(source)` check, but it may make more sense to have special copy for MSO and MSE.

Comment: Let me know if that is what you're experiencing and what your thoughts are as it will inform the direction I go with this.

Comment: ooh. Migration to <other metas> is pretty rare - I tend to punt things over to MSO when they're high quality/important but I haven't done a SU-> MSU migration in ages (so I wouldn't have seen that path). But yes that does sound a lot like what I'm experiencing, and isolated to MSE mods since we (and technically diamonded staff) are the only folks triggering that migration path.

Comment: It looks like 91% of non-returned migrations from MSE are to other metas (e.g., https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343851/was-this-answer-deleted-can-i-see-it) but it also happens from time to time between metas (e.g. https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2022/cant-log-in-to-security-stackexchange-com-anymore-with-my-openid).  In either case, migrations to non-child metas and to MSE are common enough to deserve their own cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been fixed.

Per the discussion in the comment, this was only affecting migrations performed between metas (e.g. from MSE to MSO), now the copy make clear that the target is a meta using similar language to the existing meta flow.

Comment: What about the case where a question is migrated from a main site to a *different* site's child meta?

Comment: I would expect that to be less likely, but the copy would be the same.  Going from main to main's meta gets you "discussions ... for this site", going from anywhere to MSE get "discussions ... for the Stack Exchange network", and all other migrations to metas get "discussions ... for {targetParentSiteName}".