# Post notice for posts migrated to per-site Meta gives wrongly worded reasoning again

Tags: bug, migration, per-site-meta, post-notices

On the [New Post Notices](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339700/289905) announcement, [this bug has previously been reported as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/340409/289905):

> [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [migration](/questions/tagged/migration) [per-site-meta](/questions/tagged/per-site-meta) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
>
> The wording on the migration banner is kind of awkward when a question is migrated to a Meta site. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59304821/4751173):
>
> [image: A migration post notice — see the following quote for an excerpt of the wording]
>
> > This question was migrated to [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392118/in-stack-overflow-impact-people-reached) because it can be answered by professional and enthusiast programmers.
>
> But it *was* asked on the site for “professional and enthusiast programmers”. An idea for a better wording:
>
> > This question was migrated to [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392118/in-stack-overflow-impact-people-reached) because it’s a question *about* the site for professional and enthusiast programmers.

It was marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) and Yaakov Ellis has [commented this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339700/289905#comment1139479_340409) on 2019-12-23:

> The language of the migration notice from main sites to meta sites has been updated to `This question was migrated to [$toSiteName$]($destinationUrl$), our site for discussion, support, and feature requests for this site.`

If you look at [this recent migrated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61152332/?noredirect=1), you’ll still see the old wording:

[image: A migration post notice with the same “awkward” wording]

The other example question from the older report also has the old wording, currently.

If this has previously been fixed around the end of last year, it seems that this bug has reappeared.
Since the announcement is locked, I can’t ping Yaakov there.
Unless I missed something, this needs to be fixed (again).

Comment: Quick aside about tags: the outdated [tag:post-notices] tag wiki refers to the “locked”, “citation needed”, “current event”, and “insufficient explanation” post notices; there’s also [tag:migration-notice] without a tag wiki. I’d like to update these, but I’m not sure what these two tags are supposed to be used for. There’s also the issue of [tag:post-notices] being plural whereas [tag:migration-notice] is singular.

Comment: And due to this tag inconsistency, I missed all [tag:migration-notice] questions, including this one that reports exactly the same bug: [Migration message for per-site metas make no sense](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343455/289905).