# Close reason banner not displayed to low-reputation post author

Tags: bug, status-norepro, new-users, close-reasons, post-notices

Over at Physics we have a new user whose first interaction with the site was to post an interesting but off-topic question.  They were [savvy enough to ask about it on Meta](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12714/44126), but not to follow the explanatory link in the close reason --- because it turned out, the close reason (which [until recently was visible to all users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339700/280545)) was incorrectly hidden from them.

Screenshot from diamond moderator:

[image: screenshot from moderator, message visible]

Screenshot from post author, close banner not visible:

[image: screenshot from post author, message hidden]

Comment: [tag:status-norepro] — _“You were right that an extension (although not an ad-blocker) was interfering, and I apologize to everyone here for the waste of time. This is my fault, and I'm embarrassed at having caused a commotion.”_ — [Comment from the OP](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12714/why-was-this-hot-network-question-closed#comment48001_12721).

Comment: Cant understand the question.Can you frame it in a better way?

Comment: @trusha I did my best ...