# Show suggested edit reviewers the original close reason

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits, close-reasons, vote-to-reopen

When reviewing question edits, I saw a post in the Suggested Edits queue where the edit author selected "submit for review". It was closed as one of the five site-specific reasons, but the review just showed "Not suitable for this site. This question doesn’t meet a [site] guideline."

> [image: the review]

How can a reviewer effectively decide if the edit fixed the problem without seeing the original close reason? I shouldn't have to open a new tab for this.

I was [told no for showing the close information to all users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337104/323179), but in this case reviewers will have to act on the closure. I don't see a problem with showing the close reason to reviewers without the ability to reopen here, if they can even review these.

Comment: The team [has changed their mind](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356902/please-allow-users-without-the-close-reopen-votes-privilege-to-see-the-full-deta#comment1245076_356902) on their previous decision to conceal this information. It would take some time for this to go into effect, though.