# Help center page on closed questions still incorrectly indicates that feedback on closure is private, when as of recently, it's no longer so

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, help-center, feedback

The `/help/closed-questions` page on every site says:

> If your question is closed, you will receive private feedback on the reason why it was closed.

However, following [this change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/379011/377214) to the close notices, this feedback is now shown to everyone, so as to allow for other users without the close voting privilege to edit the question to make it suitable. The part of the notice claiming it as "private feedback" has also been removed.

The word "private" in the help center page's sentence needs to be removed. It should just say "you will receive feedback" since it's not private anymore.

Comment: I'm not sure if the word "private" is incorrect. The post owner _does_ receive private feedback: it is a view only they see. If you look at the linked post, for example, post owners see "or [post a new one on Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)." which is _not_ part of the public guidance.

Comment: @HenryEcker While it's feedback, it's not feedback on the reason why it was closed.

Comment: Fair enough. The point still stands. The post owner _does_ receive private feedback no one else sees. Most closure reasons have very similar (or identical) private and public guidance, but this is not a requirement and the post owner _could_ be presented with something entirely different. This can (and has) caused issues because privileged users were unaware of exactly what guidance was being presented to the post owner.

Comment: The unification of public guidance has made this even _less_ clear. I think it _is_ important to note that the post owner sees something different than everyone else. Even if we no longer use the word "private" or change the wording so it doesn't indicate that they revive private feedback about why it was closed if that is disagreeable.

Comment: While the reason why it's closed is not private (and was never private, it's just that the "post notice close description" is too generic on many sites), I'm thinking of choosing to keep the word "private" (because "post-owner guidance" can be different from "public guidance") or to replace it with "personalized" (but not all "post-owner guidance" is personalized)...