# How to access 'Private feedback for you'?

Tags: support, closed-questions, post-notices

I got this on a question I asked (no big deal - I don't care if somebody closes it). Is this a feature? How would I access "private feedback"?

[image]

Comment: See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394492/where-is-the-private-feedback-on-a-question-closed-as-offtopic) post from Stack Overflow.

Comment: ah - ok - a bit of a counterintuitive UI tbh. Private feedback would seem to imply actual feedback rather than just a canned response but whatever. problems with UI are addressed in that ticket.

Answer (score 9):

What that text is referring to (the "private feedback") is the explanation just above it.

Here's a snip from one of my own closed questions, with the feedback this text is referring to circled:

[image: Post notice with feedback circled]

The text in this area changes depending upon who is viewing the page at a given time. The post author sees an explanation oriented just for them (hence the "private feedback for you" wording). Users with access to the [close vote privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) see the reason the question was closed as well as who voted to close it, and users who are neither the post author nor a close voter will see a minimal explanation.

Here's what I see, as a user who does not have close vote privileges, on your closed question's post notice:

[image: Non-close voter info]

Comment: thx - it seems like in the case you provide, there should be a link to the "similar question".

Comment: @timpone Yep, there is, I just didn't include the whole thing in the screenshot. Here's [the top part of that notice](https://i.imgur.com/CfEiJmC.png).

Answer (score 8):

The message that you see on the post notice *is* the private feedback. Other users won't see this exact version (though high rep users will see something similar).

Answer (score 4):

The private feedback is visible *above* that phrase, in this case something like this:

[image]

More details about these banners can be found in the announcement post: [New Post Notices are live network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339700/295232)

Comment: thx - a bit of a counterintuitive UI but those issues seem to be addressed in ticket linked in comments. Had never seen this before.