# Odd duplicates link for questions that were closed as duplicates a long time ago

Tags: bug, design, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

I occasionally notice this odd duplicate notice, but only for questions that were closed a long time ago. Apparently there was an update that changed the interface, changed how closing questions as duplicates work, but it didn't exactly migrate older questions to look correct after the update. Can this be fixed?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [New Post Notices are live network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339700/new-post-notices-are-live-network-wide) More specifically: [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339706/622284)

Comment: @Spevacus Why was that made an answer instead of a question?

Comment: Because all related bug reports to new changes are commonly made as answers to the related announcements. After a period of time, new bug reports are to be made as questions.

Comment: There also _is_ a question about it on MSO: [Question closed as duplicate, but no link given?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280655/4642212) and [This question already has answers where?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/391505/4642212). This is already well-known.